# "prefer to" Vs "prefer + rather than"

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions

1 I prefer English lessons rather than Spanish one.

2 I prefer English lessons to Spanish one.

3 I prefer coffee to chocolate.

4 I prefer coffee rather than chocolate.

5 I would prefer to make a copy than to take this whole book home.

6 I would prefer to make a copy rather than to take this whole book home.

Are these sentences correct? Can we always replace "prefer to" with"rather than" ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the answer given by @nohat on:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/which-is-correct-prefer-x-to-y-or-prefer-x-over-y

It will clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

These ones sound right:

> 3. I prefer coffee to chocolate.
> 4. I prefer coffee rather than chocolate.

These ones do not:

> 1. I prefer English lessons rather than Spanish one.
> 2. I prefer English lessons to Spanish one.

- I prefer English lessons to Spanish.
- I would prefer English lessons rather than Spanish.

  > 5. I would prefer to make a copy than to take this whole book home.
  > 6. I would prefer to make a copy rather than to take this whole book home.
- I would prefer to make a copy, rather than take this whole book home.
- I would rather take this whole book home, rather than make a copy.
- Instead of taking this whole book home, I'd rather make a copy.

"Prefer to" and "rather than" are not interchangeable.